# ¿ Cómo configurar un expandable list view dentro de un Navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, listview

He visto varias preguntas de estas pero SIEMPRE se han contestado creando un 
 " algo" y a partir de ese "algo" añadir mediante `.add` las variables que quieres dentro. Pero yo la lista ya está creada porque he usado lo que viene por defecto en **Android Studio** de `"Navigation Drawer"`, ¿Dónde tengo que poner dentro del código para que cuando pulse en **"PRIMERO"** me salgan debajo otras dos opciones?

Código java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,FragmentFirst.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        FragmentSecond.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();




    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.PRIMERO) {

        fragment = new FragmentFirst();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.SEGUNDO) {

        fragment = new FragmentSecond();
        FragmentTransaction = true;


    } else if (id == R.id.TERCERO) {

    } else if (id == R.id.CUARTO) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    if(FragmentTransaction) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_main,fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

}

---

codigo main :

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: Lo que comentas como "PRIMERO" es un grupo al cual se le agregan elementos, te agrego una respuesta con un ejemplo en el cual se configuran 3 grupos con sus respectivos elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar una librería como estas:

https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout

https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

Lo utilizaria de esta manera:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab_normal"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="-28dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/fab_anim"
        android:transitionName="fab"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/contenedor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/text">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_duration="500"
        app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sample" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/text"
    android:text="sample2" />
```

Comment: Bienvenidor a la comunidad, se ve interesantes esas librerías, sobretodo la primera

Answer (score 1):

Agregar un `ExpandableListView` a un `Navigation Drawer`, se puede realizar agregando el elemento dentro del `DrawerLayout` por ejemplo: `activity_main.xml` :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Agrego la Activity para que cargaria el layout `activity_main.xml`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapterExpandable;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // obtiene el DrawerLayout.
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // obtiene el listview.
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
        // prepara datos para Header y Listado en ExpandableListView.
        prepareListData();
        // configura Adapter.
        listAdapterExpandable = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // configura Adapter en ExpandableListView.
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapterExpandable);
        // Puedes expandir los grupos por default.
        int count = listAdapterExpandable.getGroupCount();
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            expListView.expandGroup(i);


    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Agrega Encabezados.
        listDataHeader.add("Lenguajes de Programación");
        listDataHeader.add("Tipos");
        listDataHeader.add("Paises");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> lenguajes = new ArrayList<String>();
        lenguajes.add("C++");
        lenguajes.add("Java");
        lenguajes.add("Ruby");
        lenguajes.add("Python");
        lenguajes.add("Swift");
        lenguajes.add("Objective C");
        lenguajes.add("C#");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> tipos = new ArrayList<String>();
        tipos.add("Desarrollo Mobil");
        tipos.add("Escritorio");
        tipos.add("Web");
        tipos.add("Juegos");
        tipos.add("Bases de Datos");
        tipos.add("Analisis de Datos");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> paises = new ArrayList<String>();
        paises.add("Rumania");
        paises.add("Ucrania");
        paises.add("México");
        paises.add("Grecia");
        paises.add("Holanda");
        paises.add("El Salvador");
        paises.add("Guatemala");
        paises.add("Canada");
        paises.add("Francia");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), lenguajes);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), tipos);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), paises);
    }

}
```

Custom view para el grupo: `list_group.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#FF9900" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom view de cada elemento: `list_item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

se agrega clase personalizada `ExpandableListAdapter` que extiende de `BaseExpandableListAdapter` :

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> miListDataHeader; // Titulos en encabezados.
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> miListDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.miListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.miListDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.miListDataChild.get(this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.miListDataChild.get(this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.miListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de como se vería la implementación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voy a tal cual probarlo pero no me queda igual de elegante que si uso un drawer..

Comment: a que te refieres que no queda igual de elegante? al diseño?

Comment: Sí, voy a ver porque me da error, cuando se me ejecute te aviso.

Comment: ok , simplemente revisa el LogCat ahí encontraras que es el problema.

Comment: me sale unico fallo en "ActionBarDrawerToggle" y cuando doy en importar import me sale el "import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle" y me sale error en casi todo en el MainActivity

Comment: que imports van en el Main? Porque estoy poniendo y en ese da error.

Comment: Da igual, crearé mi Navigation Drawer porque me están saliendo fallos en el .java y yo quiero que a partir del código del drawer ya creado añadir lineas, no borras cosas :S gracias todas formas, esperaré a ver más respuesta o algo ...

Comment: Ponte por favor en el chat.

Comment: en cual chat el principal???

Comment: no, en el chat privado